# Show formatted number and save double value

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have seen PDF forms where you could write numbers in your local format and the PDF stored double values in the background which could be read with PDFBox. 
How can I tell the field in my example e.g. take the number 125.5 (double) and show "125,5" (my locale)? 
And when the user edits the field, the value in the background still is a valid double. Is there some built in mechanism or how can a workaround look like? Thanks in advance.

```
public final class CreateSimpleForm
{
    private static final PDFont FONT = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    private static final float FONT_SIZE = 12;

    private CreateSimpleForm()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);

        PDResources resources = new PDResources();
        resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), FONT);

        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

        acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);

        String defaultAppearanceString = "/Helv 0 Tf 0 g";
        acroForm.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);

        PDTextField textBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        textBox.setPartialName("SampleField");
        defaultAppearanceString = "/Helv " + FONT_SIZE + " Tf 0 0 0 rg";
        textBox.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);

        acroForm.getFields().add(textBox);

        PDAnnotationWidget widget = textBox.getWidgets().get(0);
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(50, 750, 200, 50);
        widget.setRectangle(rect);
        widget.setPage(page);

        widget.setPrinted(true);
        page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

        textBox.setValue("Sample field");

        document.save("test.pdf");
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way but for now I'll leave it like that until someone comes up with a better solution.

I create my visible field with the UI representation and a hidden field with the "background" value which is formatted by javascript everytime I edit the visible field.
When I try to read the data I have to omit the visible fields and concentrate on the hidden ones.

This is the simplest solution for me (which of course needs to be cleaned up a bit)

```
public final class CreateSimpleForm {
    private static final PDFont FONT = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    private PDAcroForm acroForm;
    private String defaultAppearanceString;
    private PDPage page;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new CreateSimpleForm();
    }

    private CreateSimpleForm() throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);

        PDResources resources = new PDResources();
        resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), FONT);

        acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

        acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);

        defaultAppearanceString = "/Helv 0 Tf 0 g";
        acroForm.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);


        createFormattedField("myField", 125.5);

        document.save("test.pdf");
        document.close();
    }

    private void createFormattedField(String name, Double value) throws IOException {
        String nameHidden = name + "_hidden";
        PDTextField textBox = createField(name, false);
        textBox.setValue(String.format("%1$,.2f", value));
        createField(name + "_hidden", true).setValue(value.toString());
        PDActionJavaScript tfJs = new PDActionJavaScript("this.getField(\"" + nameHidden + "\").value = this.getField(\"" + name + "\").value.replace(/\\./g,'').replace(/\\,/g,'.');");
        PDAnnotationAdditionalActions actions = new PDAnnotationAdditionalActions();
        actions.setPC(tfJs);
        actions.setBl(tfJs);
        textBox.getWidgets().get(0).setActions(actions);
    }

    private PDTextField createField(String name, boolean hidden) throws IOException {
        PDTextField textBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        textBox.setPartialName(name);
        textBox.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);

        acroForm.getFields().add(textBox);

        PDAnnotationWidget widget = textBox.getWidgets().get(0);
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(50, 750, 200, 50);
        widget.setRectangle(rect);
        widget.setPage(page);

        widget.setPrinted(true);
        page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

        widget.setHidden(hidden);
        return textBox;
    }
}
```